# Ethminer 0 h/s while mining?

Tags: mining

Im doing an experiment and for some reason I keep mining 0 h/s?

output: https://pastebin.com/pCPrjUWa

Batch file: ethminer -G -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com/0x618aE67290bDa7707B8fDd9b070E485970D1d3bf/gushoukoens@gmail.com

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your GPU cards have < 4GB of memory

I use EthOSDistro.com which handles it all for you.  I just update my config file with my wallet address and pool and the EthOS does the rest.

I would first download ETH-Proxy https://github.com/Atrides/eth-proxy 
it is a python file. Info on the github repo to get it running.  Once this is running run the command

```
ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -F http://127.0.0.1:8080/rig
```

Hopefully you will then see it start to mine against the pool.